# Python won't detect function loop if statement correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, python-3.8

I have the following code

```
def numTest():
    getNum = "https://sms-activate.ru/stubs/handler_api.php?api_key=" + api + "&action=getNumber&service=go&country=3"
    numReq = requests.get(getNum)
    smsNum = numReq.text
    cleanNum = smsNum.split(":")
    print(cleanNum)
    reply = cleanNum[:6]
    if reply == "ACCESS":
        numID = cleanNum[1]
        smsNo = cleanNum[2].replace("1", "", 1)
        print(numID)
        print(smsNo)
    else:
        numTest()
```

When the code is ran it doesn't detect the reply properly. So the API can either get back something such as `['ACCESS_NUMBER', '379609689', '12165419985']` or this `['NO_NUMBERS']`
If it is the first one I need to split it and just keep array [1] and [2] and if it says No Numbers I need to run the loop again. What happens as well is if I get a number on the first try it stops and works correctly but if I get No numbers it trys again and if it gets a number it keeps going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleannum` is a list, you're looking to find out if the first elements first 6 characters are ACCESS, not the first 6 elements of the list (which will never equal a string)

`reply = cleanNum[0][:6]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem right. But if the array you mentioned is "cleanNum", then you should be using cleanNum[0][:6] here.